# How to show the locations from where the dependencies are downloaded in gradle?

Tags: android, gradle

Is there a way to display the urls from where the dependencies are downloaded while running gradle in android ?

Comment: gradle prints "downloading.." messages while building java projects. Does this not happen when building android projects?

Comment: Nope, I dont see it on android studio

Comment: Ah studio. try running gradle tasks from the commandline?